# Getting data via ajax does not work

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have to get data from database but my head is broken since I didn't find any error but I don't know why it doesn't work!

JavaScript

```
var editdata = document.getElementById('editdata');
editdata.onclick = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "sendata.php",
        data :{ length : length, age : age, },
        type : 'POST',
        success: function(output_data){
            $('#mydata').html(output_data);
        }
    });
}
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['editdata'])) {
    $sql4 = $db->setQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM people WHERE userid = "
        . $userid2 . " AND inf_id = " . $_SESSION['name'] . " "
    );
    $result4 = $sql4->loadAssocList() ;
    $output_data = "";
    $output_data .= "<table width='600' border='1' >";
    foreach ($result4 as $row4) {
        $output_data .= "<tr><td>".$row4['age'];
        $output_data .= "</td><td>".$row4['length'] ;
        $output_data .= "</td><td><input id ='".$row4['id']
            . "' type='button' value='Delete'/>";
        $output_data .= "</td></tr>" ;
    }
    $output_data .= "</table>" ;
    echo $output_data ;
}
echo "failure";
```

but I'm getting just a `failure` message if I do:

```
success: function(msg){
    alert(msg);
    $('#mydata').html(output_data);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try taking out the comma after age:age,

Comment: done but its not this problem

Comment: Also you're checking for $_POST['editdata'] but you are not sending that variable from your Ajax request, so that if statement is failing.

Comment: Just some hints for your further debugging: - use FireBug and FireQuery for Firefox - double check Variablenames and filenames: maybe you named the server side script senddata.php? - do some error handling on php-side: use try/catch good luck!

Comment: how to send this post['editdata'] from ajax request?

Comment: this is my button `<input type="button" id="editdata" name="editdata" value="Edit my Data" />`

Answer (score 1):

You are sending `{ length : length, age : age }` with POST method.

This means that only `$_POST['lenght']` and `$_POST['age']` are set, therefore making `(isset($_POST['editdata']))` return false and not execute the if block.

Did you mean:

```
if (isset($_POST['legth']) and isset($_POST['age'])) {
    ...
}
```

Also you can notice that `echo "failure;"` is executed every time. Maybe you meant:

```
if (isset($_POST['editdata'])) {
    ...
} else {
    echo "failure";
}
```

?

Comment: i mean if the button is set of editdata . then get data from database, i have editdata button. so i check if is clicked then get data

Comment: i think u right but how should i send also editdata ?

Comment: this is my button `<input type="button" id="editdata" name="editdata" value="Edit my Data" />`

Comment: @peter, what do you want to send as `$_POST['editdata']`? There's no value in it...

Comment: @peter using the name of the button as a `$_POST` variable only works when actually posting the form in HTML, but because you are using AJAX, only the parameters passed in the data section of the AJAX request `data :{ length : length, age : age, }` are passed to the page.